# Windows forms - The name "dataGridView2" doesn't exist in this context

Tags: c#, winforms, object

The problem is "The name "dataGridView2" doesn't exist in this context.". It only appears at the final parts of the code. Placing the object creation outside of public void menuItem1_Click fixes the problem, but then it only creates one object, I need it to create an object every time a button is pressed.

Here is the code from Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Kalkulator_Matrica
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int brojMatrice = 1;
        public int dataGridCreator = 0;

        public void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // opens form2 with new matrix
            Form2 novaMatrica = new Form2();


            using (var form = new Form2())
            {
                var result = form.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    int column = form.ReturnValue1;
                    int row = form.ReturnValue2;

                    //Create tab
                    TabPage tpage = new TabPage("Matrica " + brojMatrice);
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tpage);

                    //Create data grid
                    DataGridView dataGridView2 = new DataGridView();
                    dataGridView2.ClientSize = new Size(553, 350);
                    dataGridView2.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    dataGridView2.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
                    dataGridView2.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
                    dataGridView2.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
                    dataGridView2.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                    dataGridView2.ColumnCount = column;
                    dataGridView2.RowCount = row;
                    this.AutoSize = true;
                    tpage.Controls.Add(dataGridView2); //Add grid to tab

                    //Create matrix name label
                    Label imeMatrice = new Label();
                    imeMatrice.Location = new Point(620, 10);
                    imeMatrice.Size = new Size(100, 20);
                    imeMatrice.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15);
                    imeMatrice.Text = "Matrica " + brojMatrice;
                    tpage.Controls.Add(imeMatrice);

                    //Create matrix data label
                    Label dataMatrice = new Label();
                    dataMatrice.Location = new Point(637, 35);
                    dataMatrice.Size = new Size(100, 20);
                    dataMatrice.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15);
                    dataMatrice.Text = dataGridView2.RowCount + " x " + dataGridView2.ColumnCount;
                    tpage.Controls.Add(dataMatrice);

                    //Povecamo counter za imena matrica
                    brojMatrice += 1;

                    //Create button ADD ROW
                    Button addRow = new Button();
                    addRow.Location = new Point(557, 70);
                    addRow.Size = new Size(107, 40);
                    addRow.Text = "Dodaj redak";
                    addRow.Click += new EventHandler(addRowClick);
                    tpage.Controls.Add(addRow);

                    //Create button REMOVE ROW
                    Button removeRow = new Button();
                    removeRow.Location = new Point(663, 70);
                    removeRow.Size = new Size(107, 40);
                    removeRow.Text = "Izbrisi redak";
                    removeRow.Click += new EventHandler(removeRowClick);
                    tpage.Controls.Add(removeRow);

                    //Create button ADD COLUMN
                    Button addColumn = new Button();
                    addColumn.Location = new Point(557, 110);
                    addColumn.Size = new Size(107, 40);
                    addColumn.Text = "Dodaj stupac";
                    addColumn.Click += new EventHandler(addColumnClick);
                    tpage.Controls.Add(addColumn);

                    //Create button REMOVE COLUMN
                    Button removeColumn = new Button();
                    removeColumn.Location = new Point(663, 110);
                    removeColumn.Size = new Size(107, 40);
                    removeColumn.Text = "Izbrisi stupac";
                    removeColumn.Click += new EventHandler(removeColumnClick);
                    tpage.Controls.Add(removeColumn);


                    //Sets widght of all columns
                    for (int i = 0; i < column; i = i + 1)
                    {
                        dataGridView2.Columns[i].Width = 25;
                    }

                    dataGridCreator = dataGridCreator + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        private void addRowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.RowCount = dataGridView2.RowCount + 1;
        }
        private void removeRowClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView2.RowCount > 1) {
                dataGridView2.RowCount = dataGridView2.RowCount - 1;
            }
        }
        private void addColumnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = dataGridView2.ColumnCount + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.ColumnCount; i = i + 1)
            {
                dataGridView2.Columns[i].Width = 25;
            }
        }
        private void removeColumnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView2.ColumnCount > 1)
            {
                dataGridView2.ColumnCount = dataGridView2.ColumnCount - 1;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: place the object declaration outside of `public void menuItem1_Click`. Like so: `private DataGridView dataGridView2;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like below, it will create new object every time but name of the variable will be same through out the code and it accessible in the context as well.

```
int brojMatrice = 1;
public int dataGridCreator = 0;
DataGridView dataGridView2;

public void menuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create data grid
    dataGridView2 = new DataGridView();
}
```